# Why cannot use iterator in range-base for?

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, stl, iterator

I'm trying to iterate a std::list and do some work for each of the elements, and maybe remove some of them. To remove an element, using erase function should be faster than using remove function, so I need to iterate it with iterator. I think range-base for can help me but it doesn't. It seems to me (maybe also to many others) that c++11 range-based for is using iterator. And I have check [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) which says

```
for ( range_declaration : range_expression ) loop_statement
```

will give

```
{
  auto && __range = range_expression ; 
  for (auto __begin = begin_expr,
  __end = end_expr; 
  __begin != __end; ++__begin) { 
    range_declaration = *__begin; 
    loop_statement 
  } 
}
```

where `begin_expr` is `__range.begin()`. But I have tried this code:

```
typedef std::list<int> IntList;
IntList i;
for (IntList::iterator a : i)
{
}
```

and it does not compile. If changed to

```
typedef std::list<int> IntList;
IntList i;
for (int a : i)
{
}
```

It works well. So now I think range-based for is not using iterators (that is, not begin function), but is using something else. So why cannot?

I have tried the code on Visual C++ 2013 CTP and g++.

**EDIT**

Yes, I didn't notice the '*'. As the operator* is called, I can not use iterator any more. That's my fault.

Another question is whether I can use erase of std::list during iterating. Again it's my fault. After thinking again, the only way is to use ordinary for and before remove, get the iterator to next element. In fact I was told not modify any container when iterating, but I misunderstood the reference which says that iterator of list is still valid after modification to the container. So I'll find some other way to do it. Anyway, thank you for your remind! @Theolodis

Comment: **Do not delete from a List when you are in a ranged based loop!**

Comment: Use `auto` with ranged for-loops.

Comment: To add to 40two's comment, often `auto&&` is the appropriate solution. Make sure you understand the difference.

Comment: it IS using iterators, but it `int a` is an INT, and INT is not an iterator, it is the value that the iterator holds, like with a map it would be std::pair instead of int.

Comment: Just for the future - "It did not compile" may be a true statement, but it is also not very helpful.  Surely the compiler gave you an error message, and that error message usually tells you *why* it did not compile.  That information will usually help others (or you!) understand what is happening.

Comment: If you want to conditionally remove items from a list, look into the erase/remove idiom in C++ (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom) This will probably be more concise and less prone to error than what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the line:

```
range_declaration = *__begin;
```

Here, we dereference the hidden iterator, and assign the value to the mutable part of your for statement.

The iterator itself (the result of `begin(__range)` and `end(__range)`) is hidden from you. The compiler will create variables for it in the background that are not visible to you. What you see is the result of `*__begin`. In this case, that would be the `value_type` of your container, which is an `int`.

---

Additionally, modifying a container while you are iterating over it is often quite dangerous, so make sure you read up on iterator invalidation (which applies with this range for loop).

The usual way to erase from a container in c++ is to use the erase-remove idiom. In C++11, it would look something like this if, for example, we wanted to remove all even numbers.

```
IntList i;
auto is_even = [](int arg) -> bool { return arg % 2 == 0; };
i.erase(std::remove_if(i.begin(), i.end(), is_even), i.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the line

```
range_declaration = *__begin;
```

The `range declaration` gets the value of iterator dereferenced (`*`). So the iterators may be used internally, but you have access to their values only.